# Determine the value of $p\ge0$ for which the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n(-1)^n}{(1+n^2)^p}$ is divergent, conditionally convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Determine the value of $p\ge0$ for which the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n(-1)^n}{(1+n^2)^p}$$ is divergent, conditionally convergent or absolutely convergent.

I have done the absolute convergent part. $$\left|\frac{n(-1)^n}{(1+n^2)^p}\right|\le \left|\frac{n}{(1+n^2)^p} \right|\le\left| \frac{1}{(1+n^2)^p}\right|\le\left|\frac{1}{n^{2p}} \right|$$ Hence, by comparison test, the series converges absolutely when $p>\frac{1}{2}$.

Is this series diverges when $p\le\frac{1}{2}$? I have no idea how to show that for what $p$ it will converges conditionally. Thanks for any comments.

Comment: Is second inequality right? How's $n\leq 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute convergence comes from
$$\left|\frac{n(-1)^n}{(1+n^2)^p}\right| \sim \frac{1}{n^{2p-1}}$$
so you need $2p-1>1$.

Conditional convergence we will have when $2p-1>0$

**Addition.**

For conditional convergence we need $\frac{n}{(1+n^2)^p} \to 0$ monotonously. Possibly most easy way to prove is consider  $f(x)=\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^p}$ and  calculate $f'(x)=\frac{1+x^2(1-2p)}{(1+x^2)^{p+1}}$, from where, for $2p-1>0$ we obtain desired.

On another hand if there is some reason to want solve inequality $\frac{n+1}{(1+(n+1)^2)^p} \leqslant \frac{n}{(1+n^2)^p}$ straight ahead, then we can write $(n+1)(1+n^2)^p \leqslant n(1+(n+1)^2)^p$ and notice, that while maximal power of $n$ on both sides is $n^{2p+1}$ with same coefficient $1$, then member $n^{2p}$ on left side have coefficient $1$ and on right side coefficient $2p$. So, again, we obtain decreasing when $2p-1>0$.

Comment: how to know that if $2p-1>0$, then the series converges conditionally?

Comment: $\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}} \to 0$ monotonically when $\alpha>0$.

Comment: I know that if $\frac{n}{(1+n^2)^p}$ decreases monotonically, then it will converge. But how to show that $\frac{n}{(1+n^2)^p}$ decreases monotonically?

Comment: One possibility is consider $f(x)=\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^p}$ and take derivative $f'(x)=\frac{1+x^2(1-2p)}{(1+x^2)^{p+1}}$

Comment: I think if $x$ is large, then $f'(x)\le 0$, and I'm stuck at this $\frac{n+1}{(1+(n+1)^2)^p} \le \frac{n}{(1+n^2)p}$, the inequality is what I want to show that it decreases monotonically. But I can not get it because $p\ge\frac{1}{2}$ is a unknown number. What can I do to get the inequality? thanks for your comments.

Comment: From derivative I wrote above in comments you have $f'<0$ when $x^2>\frac{1}{2p-1}$. Are you agree?

Comment: I think it is $1+x^2(1-2p)<0$, so $x^2>\frac{1}{1-2p}$

Comment: When member $x^2(1-2p)$ goes to right side of inequality, does it change sign?

Comment: Yes. $1<-x^2(1-2p)=x^2(2p-1)$, but I don't know the sign of $2p-1$.

Comment: We can say, that when $2p-1>0$, then $f$ is decreasing and it's all what we want.

Comment: Do you know how to prove $\frac{n}{(1+n^2)^p}$ decreases monotonically? I'm stuck at $\frac{n+1}{(1+(n+1)^2)^p} \le \frac{n}{(1+n^2)p}$.

Comment: Added to answer.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.